# Order By Flyer Likes Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to order travel flyers by how many likes a travel flyers has. I already have the flyers and likes table. I just dont know how would I count the flyers like and order them by highest when likwe tag is clicked on. As u can see, I already have a like counter for each flyer with the thumbs up icon
[image]

Flyers Table:

```html
Schema::create('flyers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('excerpt');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Likeable Table:

( 'likeable_id' is the flyers id, and 'likeable_type' is from what model the like was placed, for example if a person liked a flyer it would be App\Flyer, or if a person liked an image it would be App\Image )

```html
Schema::create('likeable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('likeable_id');
            $table->string('likeable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is the OrderByController.php

As you can see I already have order by date asc, and desc

```html
class OrderByController extends TravelFlyersController {

    /**
     * @param Flyer $flyer
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function travelDateAsc(Flyer $flyer)
    {
        $flyer = Flyer::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(15);

        return view('travelflyers.index', ['flyer' => $flyer]);
    }


    /**
     * @param Flyer $flyer
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function travelDateDesc(Flyer $flyer)
    {
        $flyer = Flyer::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);

        return view('travelflyers.index', ['flyer' => $flyer]);
    }


    public function flyerLikes(Like $like)
    {
        // DONT KNOW HOW TO COUNT THE FLYERS HERE NEED HELP HERE
         // MAYBE SOMETHING LIKE THIS, (that does not work though)

        $flyer = Flyer::findOrFail($id);

        $flyers = Like::orderBy('likeable_id')->where('likeable_id', '=',     $flyer);
        return view('travelflyers.index', ['flyers' => $flyers]);
    }


}
```

The Routes:

```html
    Route::get('travelflyers/date/asc', [
        'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\OrderByController@travelDateAsc',
        'as'   => 'travelflyers.asc',
    ]);


    Route::get('travelflyers/date/desc', [
        'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\OrderByController@travelDateDesc',
        'as'   => 'travelflyers.desc',
    ]);



    Route::get('travelflyers/likes', [
        'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\OrderByController@flyerLikes',
        'as'   => 'travelflyers.likes',
    ]);
```

And the blade:

```html
                 <a href="{{ route('travelflyers.desc') }}" class="ui green large label">
                    Newest
                </a>
                <a href="{{ route('travelflyers.asc') }}" class="ui orange large label">
                    Oldest
                </a>


                <a href="{{ route('travelflyers.likes') }}" class="ui orange large label">
                    Likes
                </a>
```

/**** EDIT ********/

```html
public function flyerLikes(Flyer $flyer) {

        $flyer = Flyer::has('likeable', '>=', 1)
            ->select(DB::raw('id, count(likeable_id) as likes, user_id'))
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderBy('likes', 'desc')
            ->get();


        return view('travelflyers.index', ['flyer' => $flyer]);
}
```

Comment: I think You need pivot table with fields: user_id, flyer_id

Comment: im wondering where are u getting likes from, beacuse I dont have that in my db

Answer (score 0):

I can make a mistake, but that's something kind of

-- edited --

```
$flyers = Flier::has('flyers', '>=', 1)
        ->select(\DB::raw('flyers.id, count(flyers.id) as likes, users.id'))
        ->join('likeable', 'users.id', '=', 'likeable.user_id')
        ->join('flyers', 'likeable.flier_id', '=', 'flyers.id')
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->orderBy('likes', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I edited my post look at the very bottom, that is waht I have for my function, but when i click on likes button, I get error **No query results for model [App\Flyer]**

Comment: i switched my route to travelflyers/most/likes, and i get thos error **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::likeable_id()**

Comment: ok, if u want we can use a software were you can see my computer and check my code

Comment: How do U get flyers with likes? Would u like to go to another messenger?

Comment: ya sure which messinger?

Comment: skupe: Yurkoo008 , telegram +380681072006

Comment: sorry, dont have Skype, is there something were you can go on my computer remotely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102934/discussion-between-yurich-and-david).